# Laravel select data by month to month with a different year

Tags: laravel, web, eloquent

How can I select data in a controller by month to month?

**For example:** I want to show data from June 2019 to July 2020.

Comment: can you display a little more, like your database... the easiest one is like this `$data  = Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();` where `$from = june 2019` and so on

Comment: $from = 01 - 01 - 2019;
        $to = 01 - 06 - 2020;
        $total = Tunggakan::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
                ->get()
                ->sum("total");

Comment: i added this but its shows nothing to my app

Comment: `$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereColumn([
                    ['created_at', '>', $from],
                    ['created_at', '<', $to]
                ])->get();`

Use like this.

Comment: date should follow `Y-m-d` if you use mysql, can you show you migration file so that we can have ideas

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$start = Carbon::parse('2019-06-01')->format('Y-m');
$end = Carbon::parse('2020-07-12')->format('Y-m');

Model::whereBetween('column_name', [$start, $end])->get();
```

Comment: almost work! my data still wont show

Comment: @LutfiArdiansyah please show your migration file, if this code is not working then we can have a review

Comment: show your data as image plz